# Superimpose posterior distribution on mean like cat's eye visualization from cumming

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bayesian, confidence-interval

I personally like the cat's eye visualization of Cumming that superimposes a sampling distribution over a point estimate: [image]

I would also like to do this with the posterior distribution that is obtained by the Scripts of Kruschke (2015):

```
plotMCMC( mcmcCoda , data=myData , 
      compValMu=100.0 , ropeMu=c(99.0,101.0) ,
      compValSigma=15.0 , ropeSigma=c(14,16) ,
      compValEff=0.0 , ropeEff=c(-0.1,0.1) ,
      pairsPlot=TRUE , showCurve=FALSE ,
      saveName=fileNameRoot , saveType=graphFileType )

 # Set up window and layout:


openGraph(width=6.0,height=8.0*3/5)
  layout( matrix( c(2,3,5, 1,4,6) , nrow=3, byrow=FALSE ) )
  par( mar=c(3.5,3.5,2.5,0.5) , mgp=c(2.25,0.7,0) )
  # Select thinned steps in chain for plotting of posterior predictive     curves:
  nCurvesToPlot = 20
  stepIdxVec = seq( 1 , chainLength , floor(chainLength/nCurvesToPlot) )
  # Compute limits for plots of data with posterior pred. distributions
  y = data
  xLim = c( min(y)-0.1*(max(y)-min(y)) , max(y)+0.1*(max(y)-min(y)) )
  xBreaks = seq( xLim[1] , xLim[2] , 
                 length=ceiling((xLim[2]-xLim[1])/(sd(y)/4)) )
  histInfo = hist(y,breaks=xBreaks,plot=FALSE)
  yMax = 1.2 * max( histInfo$density )
  xVec = seq( xLim[1] , xLim[2] , length=501 )
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Plot data y and smattering of posterior predictive curves:
  histInfo = hist( y , prob=TRUE , xlim=xLim , ylim=c(0,yMax) , breaks=xBreaks,
                   col="red2" , border="white" , xlab="y" , ylab="" , 
                   yaxt="n" , cex.lab=1.5 , main="Data w. Post. Pred." )
  for ( stepIdx in 1:length(stepIdxVec) ) {
    lines(xVec, dt( (xVec-mu[stepIdxVec[stepIdx]])/sigma[stepIdxVec[stepIdx]], 
                    df=nu[stepIdxVec[stepIdx]] )/sigma[stepIdxVec[stepIdx]] , 
          type="l" , col="skyblue" , lwd=1 )
  }
  text( max(xVec) , yMax , bquote(N==.(length(y))) , adj=c(1.1,1.1) )
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  histInfo = plotPost( mu , cex.lab = 1.75 , showCurve=showCurve ,
                       compVal=compValMu , ROPE=ropeMu ,
                       xlab=bquote(mu) , main=paste("Mean") , 
                       col="skyblue" )
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  histInfo = plotPost( sigma , cex.lab=1.75 , showCurve=showCurve ,
                       compVal=compValSigma , ROPE=ropeSigma , cenTend="mode" ,
                       xlab=bquote(sigma) , main=paste("Scale") , 
                       col="skyblue" )
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  effectSize = ( mu - compValMu ) / sigma
  histInfo = plotPost( effectSize , compVal=compValEff ,  ROPE=ropeEff ,
                       showCurve=showCurve , cenTend="mode" ,
                       xlab=bquote( ( mu - .(compValMu) ) / sigma ),
                       cex.lab=1.75 , main="Effect Size" ,
                       col="skyblue" )
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  postInfo = plotPost( log10(nu) , col="skyblue" , # breaks=30 ,
                       showCurve=showCurve ,
                       xlab=bquote("log10("*nu*")") , cex.lab = 1.75 , 
                       cenTend="mode" ,
                       main="Normality" ) #  (<0.7 suggests kurtosis)
```

Which looks in the end like this for the mean [image]

Is it possible to superimpose the histogram on the mean like Cumming does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a function called `plotViolin` for another application that should do what you want, or at least be easily modifiable to the specifics of your application. You can find the function about half way down the R script linked here: https://osf.io/wt4vf/

Comment: In line with this answer, `ggplot2` has a `geom_violin` that will do this.